# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader in Apache TomEE when trying to use Jackson instead of Johnzon as JSON provider

Tags: java, json, tomcat, jackson, tomee-7

Starting from [my original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359380/jsonserialize-jsondeserialize-not-working-in-apache-tomcat-tomee), I get that I need to specifically configure Apache TomEE to use Jackson as JSON provider (instead of the default Johnzon).

I imported the following in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <!-- I only need this first one because otherwise it's ommited due to a conflict.... -->
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

After this, I tried several ways:

Mentioning the provider in the *ejb-jar.xml* file

```
<pojo-deployment  class-name="jaxrs-application">
    <properties>
        cxf.jaxrs.providers = com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
    </properties>
</pojo-deployment>
```

Extending the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider with a custom class and registering it:

```
 @Provider
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public class TGJSONProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {
 }
```

**No matter what I do (or even if I don't add anything, I have the same PROBLEM:**

```
2019-05-31 16:11:35 SEVERE org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$MethodInvocation invoke error invoking org.apache.tomee.webservices.TomeeJaxRsService@12bfd80d
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    ...
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
```

What am I missing / doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "Johnzon as JSON" ?

Comment: Johnzon is the default buid-in JSON provider in Apache TomEE. I need to use Jackson instead.

Comment: You need to add dependency to [JSR311 API](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1)

Comment: @MichałZiober I thought that one is included in the Java EE API, for a long time...

I tried what you suggested, I just ended up having much older versions of some classes in my libraries, and therefore with compilation errors in other parts of the project. I don't think that 's the solution...